# How to reload the current page on click of a button in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a requirement where I have refresh the contents of the current page onclick of the refresh button in the current page.I went through few websites but I am not quite clear about this functionality.Could anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Can yopu add your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: post your code and be more specific. What do you need to reload? Is it the content of the page? In this page do you make and api call or something like this? Use a refresher, it's better, it's cleaner, has a better UX.

Answer (score 8):

Onclick of your refresh button, you could call the page event method ionViewWillEnter()

*From the official docs* --> ionViewWillEnter()  Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.

HTML

```
<button (click)="refreshPage()">Refresh Page</button>
```

Typescript

```
    ionViewWillEnter(){
            this.myDefaultMethodToFetchData();
        }

    refreshPage() {
        this.ionViewWillEnter();
    }

    myDefaultMethodToFetchData(){
        ...Do Something, when the page opens...
    }
```

Comment: this is worked for me ... easy to reuse ... very simple and fast solution. tnx

Answer (score 0):

This will work!!!
Give this under the function that's called on button click event.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

or

Use the ionViewWillEnter lifecycle event on your page.
You can put the correct code in that method to refresh all the necessary things on your page.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the constructor and just replace your page name

```
    this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
           if (e instanceof NavigationEnd && e.url === '/page-name' && localStorage.getItem('prevUrl') === '/page-name') {
            this.ionViewWillEnter();
            this.ngOnInit
           }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Just pop one page and then push that page again.
Hope this will help :)

this.navCtrl.pop();
this.navCtrl.push(NewPage);